# Какая разница между блоком и контейнером в БЭМ?

Tags: css, бэм

В [документации по БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) есть примеры блоков и элементов. Там если внутри элемента с тегом header поместить элемент с тэгом div, то это будет вложенный блок, а если внутри элемента с тегом form поместить элемент с тэгом input, то элемент с тегом input будет элементом. По каким характеристикам можно отличать блоки и элементы? Если я в элемент с тегом header помещу элемент с тегом div, а внутрь него помещу элемент с тегом p, то чем будет элемент с тегом p – элементом или блоком?

Comment: Если p последний элемент в блоке, то это будет элементом, а если тег сделан как контейнер для других тегов, то будет блоком. Аналогично с дивами.

Comment: Разделение на блоки и элементы чисто логическое и в некоторой степени вкусовщина. Основной критерий это самодостаточность. Элемент без блока не имеет смысла. Но никакой однозначного критерия нет и есть куча случаем когда выбор между блоком и элементом основывается на «мне кажется так лучше»

Comment: @SwaD То есть элемент - это то, во что ничего не вложено? Если я добавлю в тег nav пять ссылок, где в ссылку будет вложен текст и картинка, то ссылка будет блоком?

Comment: И да и нет. Вот nav можно считать блоком точно